# DB and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get from a search request to the site of the DB the sourcecode of the website and read out later values. However, I'm using BeautifulSoup and get a different sourcecode than in the browser! Have anyone an idea why this happens?

```
import bs4
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dox?S=8000096&Z=8079090&start=1")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting headers in bs4 to match your browser to see if you get similar results then?

Comment: At the moment I have not done anything with the files from bs4. Just tried the code and get another result than the browser shows.

Comment: You also need to run a `read()` on the command in `page`; otherwise it will only return a Response object

Comment: I run read() after teh command in page, but have just the same problem